# How to specify a mount path with a dot in Azure Web app mount storage

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, docker-compose

I'm building an Azure Web App using the Docker Compose option to setup a WordPress site. I have a SQL script to initialise the MySQL database which needs to be in the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. I've uploaded the script to an Azure storage container but when I try to add a path mount to the web app with the `Mount path` set to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` I get the error `The parameter 'AzureStoragePropertyDictionary' has an invalid value. Details: Mount path contains invalid characters. Please review documentation for a list of valid mount path characters`. Changing the `Mount path` to `/docker-entrypoint-initdbd/` (without the dot) allows the path mount to be saved but of course the script is not run when the app starts.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:   db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpresspassword
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - InitDb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpresspassword
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress 
volumes:   
    db_data:
```

This is the CLI script I'm using to create the path mount in the web app

```
az webapp config storage-account add -g MyRG -n MyWA --custom-id InitDb --storage-type AzureFiles --account-name MySA --share-name MyShareName --access-key MyAccessKey --mount-path /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Answer (score 6):

As I know, I'm afraid that you cannot achieve it. In Azure Web App, the mount path does not support the dot in the path and you can see the limitation in the portal:

[image]

For now, I recommend you create the image that copies the files you need when creating. Then use the image directly.

Comment: I do not know why someone will vote down this answer, do not agree with it? Just add the answer that you think it's right and show the proof. It's so impolite to vote down the answer without any reason!